# Dividing each row by the previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['city'] = ['NY','NY','LA','LA']
df['hour'] = ['0','12','0','12']
df['value'] = [12,24,3,9]

   city hour value
0   NY  0   12
1   NY  12  24
2   LA  0   3
3   LA  12  9
```

I want, for each city, to divide each row by the previous one and write the result into a new dataframe. The desired output is:

```
city ratio
NY   2
LA   3
```

What's the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: There is multiple rows per group, more as 2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First divide by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)ed values per groups:

```
df['ratio'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby('city')['value'].shift(1))
print (df)
  city hour  value  ratio
0   NY    0     12    NaN
1   NY   12     24    2.0
2   LA    0      3    NaN
3   LA   12      9    3.0
```

Then remove `NaN`s and select only `city` and `ratio` column:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['ratio'])[['city', 'ratio']]
print (df)
  city  ratio
1   NY    2.0
3   LA    3.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually all the proposed solutions are working, I'll choose this one for its simplicity.

Comment: @sato - Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
In [20]: df[['city']].assign(ratio=df.groupby('city').value.pct_change().add(1)).dropna()

Out[20]: 
  city  ratio
1   NY    2.0
3   LA    3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This'll do it:

```
df.groupby('city')['value'].agg({'ratio': lambda x: x.max()/x.min()}).reset_index()
#  city  ratio
#0   LA      3
#1   NY      2
```

Comment: If there is multiple values it return something else, not divide by shifted column.

Comment: @jezrael True, but given the data OP provided I figured this would be in accordance with his desired output.

Answer (score 1):

one way is,

```
df.groupby(['city']).apply(lambda x:x['value']/x['value'].shift(1))
```

for further improvement,

```
print df.groupby(['city']).apply(lambda x:(x['value']/x['value'].shift(1)).fillna(method='bfill'))).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['city']).drop('level_1',axis=1)

  city  value
0   LA    3.0
2   NY    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using a custom function. It assumes you want to ignore the `NaN` rows in the result of dividing one series by a shifted version of itself.

```
def divider(x):
    return x['value'] / x['value'].shift(1)

res = df.groupby('city').apply(divider)\
        .dropna().reset_index()\
        .rename(columns={'value': 'ratio'})\
        .loc[:, ['city', 'ratio']]

print(res)

  city  ratio
0   LA    3.0
1   NY    2.0
```